# JavaScript code is not working, wrote this code to validate my form but it does not work

Tags: javascript, html

A form that insert data into mysql but before inserting data I wanted to write a JavaScript that will validate the form before submit but can let it work. In the HTML I have added required and pattern attribute for the input to validate the form data and to check whether user fill the required fields but i also want to add a script that will also validate the form and show the a message in the  tag with id errorMessage but it doesn't seem to work.

```js
var inputFields = document.theForm.getElementsByTagName("input");


for (key in inputFields) {

  var myField = inputFields[key];
  var myError = document.getElementById('errorMessage');

  myField.onchange = function() {
      var myPattern = this.pattern;
      var myPlaceholder = this.placeholder;
      var isValid = this.value.search(myPattern) >= 0;

      if (!(isValid)) {
        myError.innerHTML = "Input does not match expected pattern. " + myPlaceholder;
      } else { //pattern not valid
        myError.innerHTML = "";
      } //pattern is valid

    } // myField has changed



} // inputFields
```

```html
<form id="createForm" name="theForm" method="post" action="createUser.php">
  <legend><span class="icon"><img src="/registerUser/img/createIcon.png"></span> Create New User</legend>
  <p><span id="requiredfields">* required field.</span>
  </p>

  <span id="formMessage" class="message"> </span>
  <span id="errorMessage"> </span>

  <input id="fname" type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Name *" pattern="[A-Za-z ]+" required>
  <br>
  <br>

  <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email *" required>
  <br>
  <br>

  <input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username *" required>
  <br>
  <br>

  <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password *" required>
  <br>
  <br>

  <label for="roles">Roles:</label>
  <select id="role" name="roles">
    <option>Select Role</option>
    <option value="empty"></option>
    <option value="Reporter">Reporter</option>
    <option value="Lover">Lover</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <br>

  <input id="create" type="submit" name="createUser" value="Create User">

</form>
```

Comment: Huh? Your question title says the that you have "code working" and "it does work". So what is the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work. Is there any error messages in the console? Does the form submit anyway (this may be due to an error in your script)

Comment: `document.theForm.getElementsByTagName("input");
` ???? Where did  `theForm` came in between ?

Comment: There's nothing in your script that disables form submission. It just displays a message in the `errorMessage` field if an element is invalid.

Comment: @noob If there's an element `<form name="theForm">`, `document.theForm` will refer to it automatically.

Comment: sorry meant to say it wasn't working

Comment: Does no error message, just doesn't work

Comment: @Ranaz116: You should make a jsfiddle and add it to your question.

Comment: @Barmar: Ok, I didn't knew that. Thanks !

Comment: Note that you shouldn't use a for..in loop to iterate over arrays or array-like objects. Use a traditional for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you specify an input element validation pattern as an html5 attribute like this:

```
pattern="[A-Za-z ]+"
```

...the browser checks that the whole input value matches the pattern. In other words, your pattern is treated like `^[A-Za-z ]+$` *even though the `^` and `$` are not explicitly in the pattern.*

But in your JavaScript code when you use the pattern like this:

```
var myPattern = this.pattern; // get pattern from element
var isValid = this.value.search(myPattern) >= 0;
```

...the `.search()` method doesn't try to match the whole string, it returns the index of the first pattern match within the string. Which means that, e.g., in the case of your Name field your JS will consider it valid as long as at least one character matches the pattern, even if other characters don't.

The simplest way to work around this is to update your pattern:

```
pattern="^[A-Za-z ]+$"
```

Or you could update your JS something to be something like the following:

```
var isValid = !myPattern || this.value.search("^" + myPattern + "$") >= 0;
```

That is, put `^` and `$` around the pattern to force JS to match the whole string against the pattern, but only do the test if a non-blank pattern was specified for the field (some of your fields don't have a pattern).